# behave : The term 'behave' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation, python-behave

I get this error when trying to get the python step definitions.

Error:

"behave: The term 'behave' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

I have already installed behave and selenium through pip install, I also verified their installation by the pip list command.

How to eliminate this error and get the python step definitions, I am currently on VScode, willing to approach this completely as well, in the end, I just need to be able to convert my gherkin feature file to python step definitions.

I have attached an image of the error as well for those that want to refer to it

Answer (score 1):

Add behave path to PATH in environment variables. RESTART SYSTEM.